# laravel get the filename of all records od my database

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I want to get from all of my records the value of the filename fields but i have this error. Can anyone help me?

My Code:

> > $acao = Acao::where('estado_id', '1');
> >
> > if($acao->count() >= 1) {
> >
> > $filename = $acao->imagem;
> >
> > $path = asset('images/acoes/'.$filename);
> >
> > return view ('CFAE.index', compact('path'))->withAcoes($acao);
> >
> > }else{
> >
> > return view ('CFAE.index')->withAcoes($acao);
> >
> > }

And the laravel show me this error:

> > Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$imagem

Comment: What value does $acao = Acao::where('estado_id', '1');

fetches?

Comment: the intention is to find all the records with estado_id = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `first()` method to get an object:

```
$acao = Acao::where('estado_id', '1')->first();
```

You do not use it, so you get an instance of Query Builder which doesn't have `imagem` property.

Also, to check if object is found or not, do this:

```
if (!is_null($acao)) {
```

Comment: if i do $acao = Acao::where('estado_id', '1')->first(), i will have all the records with that condition (estado_id = 1)

Comment: @Nuno no, you will get an object.

Comment: @AlexeyMenezin ok, and how i need to do to get all the records with the condition (estado_id = 1)

Comment: @Nuno to get a collection, you need to use `get()` instead of `first()`, but then you'll need to iterate over it to perform an action with every object in the collection.

Comment: can you guve me an exemple?

Comment: @Nuno I'm not sure about what exactly you're trying to achieve, but you can iterate over a collection like this `foreach ($collection as $item) { echo $item->id; }`

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
$acao = Acao::where('estado_id', '1')->get();
```

you get collection of models not model so you need to do

```
foreach($acao as $val)
{
   $val->imagem
}
```

or you could use

```
$acao = Acao::where('estado_id', '1')->first();
```

Comment: if i do $acao = Acao::where('estado_id', '1')->first(), i will have all the records with that condition (estado_id = 1) ?

Comment: No only the first record object

Comment: To get all the records use get(); and then iterate as shown above in my example